# Unable to connect Redis Instance from GKE pod - Connection to Redis <IP:6379 >failed after 2 failures.Last Error : (110) Operation timed out

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I have GKE cluster that I created with following command:

```
$ gcloud container clusters create stage1 \
  --enable-ip-alias \
  --release-channel stable \
  --zone us-central1 \
  --node-locations us-central1-a,us-central1-b
```

and I also created a redis instance with following command:

```
$ gcloud redis instances create redisbox --size=2 --region=us-central1 --redis-version=redis_5_0
```

I have retrieved the IP address of the redis instance with:

```
$ gcloud redis instances describe redisbox --region=us-central1
```

I have updated this IP in my PHP application, built my docker image , created the pod in GKE cluster. When pod is created the container throws following error

> Connection to Redis :6379 failed after 2 failures.Last Error : (110) Operation timed out

Note 1: This is working application in hosted environment and we are migrating to Google Cloud
Note 2: GKE and Redis instance is in same region
Note 3: Enabled IP aliasing in cluster

Comment: May be port access/whitelisting issue

Comment: Do you have firewall rules? Do you use the same VPC? GKE Network Policy enabled?

Comment: I have not done any other configuration than mentioned in this post. I have not created  firewall rules and no GKE policy enabled. What I have done is created VPC-native cluster by giving the option --enable-ip-alias

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing this VPC-native GKE cluster and Redis instance with your `gcloud` commands, I could check that both the nodes and their pods can reach the *redisbox* host, for example with `ncat` in a `debian:latest` pod:

```
$ REDIS_IP=$(gcloud redis instances describe redisbox --format='get(host)' --region=us-central1)
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials stage1 --region=us-central1
$ kubectl exec -ti my-debian-pod -- /bin/bash -c "ncat $REDIS_IP 6379 <<<PING"
    +PONG
```

Therefore, I suggest that you try performing this lower-level reachability test in case there there is an issue with the specific request that your PHP application is doing.

Comment: I have resolved the issue by creating the VPC native cluster and redis instance directly from google console (without commands). I have grabbed the command for creating VPC native cluster but there is no option for getting the command for creating redis   . I wont be able to use this approach asI am planning to automate this process